# jquery.js and jquery.min.js is conflict to each other

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

[image]

How to solve two jquery conflict in my html file, I have pasted the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>    
<!--Navigation Scripts-->    

<!--Image Slider Scripts-->    
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If I remove any one of them (script) then it will be work fine but one of these does not working, else whether it be anyone.

Upper one jquery.js is for navigation bar and another one jquery.min.js is for sliding banner script.

Comment: Both seems like jQuery libraries to me

Comment: what should I do now..?? dear.alien

Comment: jquery.js is uncompressed and jquery.min.js is compressed, and its depend on you which one you like to load. But load only one file.

Comment: Keep only one, use the console, see if your plugin files are up to date, as some methods might deprecate in the newer versions of jquery, so accordingly retain the library best suited, and get rid of another one

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: @Barmar actually he is not even aware that both are libraries...

Comment: wait i'll will try, dear.allan chua

Comment: @Mr.Alien , jogesh_pi , Allan Chua : i have attached my query file please solve my prob out...

Comment: How this question has not been deleted is beyond me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you include only one jQuery library into your application. You probably have a problem with versioning, I mean your navigation bar and sliding banner script use different versions of jQuery. What you should do is visit vendor websites and look at their versions, then accordingly pick one version of jQuery library that will suit both of your vendor libraries.

You can see avalaible jQuery versions here http://code.jquery.com/jquery/

*When you pick a correct version, use minified version for performance.*

Comment: just a min, I'll try,

Comment: can you please suggest me which one of them i will put.

Comment: No, because I don't know which libraries do you use. If 'you-feel-lucky' you can try http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Comment: Okay, let's first try this one: http://212.71.233.24/jquery.js for your jquery inclusion `<script>` element. Include only one.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove both of them and add the code below:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it will solve your problem. I assume that the both of them are jQuery scripts and not your own javascript file. jQuery.min.js is much better because it loads faster from the web  server due to it's minification.

NOTE Using the jquery.min.js script hosted by google will make your site load faster because this script might be already on the clients computer because the user might have already navigated to a site that cached the same script.

Comment: where did you put this script? Can you please show us how do you reference code from both libraries?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need both. Just pick one, preferably the latest version.

Comment: i'll try wait a min dear